# class instance can not assign to inherited interface

Tags: c#, interface, casting

I have two interface declaration and three class declaration, the relationship between them are like this:

```
interface IProtocolPackage
{
 ///some declaration
}
public class ProtocolPackage : IProtocolPackage
{
 ///implementation code for IProtocolPackage
}
interface IProtocolPackage<T> : IProtocolPackage
{
 ///some declaration
}
public class BytesProtocolPackage : ProtocolPackage, IProtocolPackage<byte[]>
{
///implementation code for IProtocolPackage<byte[]>
}
public class ChargingPileProtocolPackage : BytesProtocolPackage
{
///implementation code for IProtocolPackage<byte[]>
}
```

Then there is an method take IProtocolPackage type as parameter like this:

```
public void DecodeCommand(IProtocolPackage<byte> package)
    {
        ///implementation code forDecodeCommand
    }
```

but the compiler shows error says:
cannot convert from 'ChargingPileCommandCoder.ChargingPileProtocolPackage' to 'SHWDTech.Platform.ProtocolCoding.Coding.IProtocolPackage'  ChargingPileCommandCoder

I thought I have inherited interface IProtocolPackage with class ChargingPileProtocolPackage.
How does this happen?

the code where error happend:

```
public IProtocolPackage DecodeProtocol(byte[] bufferBytes, Protocol matchedProtocol)
    {
        var package = new ChargingPileProtocolPackage { Protocol = matchedProtocol, ReceiveDateTime = DateTime.Now };

        var structures = matchedProtocol.ProtocolStructures.ToList();

        var currentIndex = 0;

        for (var i = 0; i < structures.Count; i++)
        {
            var structure = structures.First(obj => obj.StructureIndex == i);

            var componentDataLength = structure.StructureName == StructureNames.Data && structure.StructureDataLength == 0
                ? Globals.BytesToInt16(package["DataLength"].ComponentContent, 0, true)
                : structure.StructureDataLength;

            if (currentIndex + componentDataLength > bufferBytes.Length)
            {
                package.Status = PackageStatus.NoEnoughBuffer;
                return package;
            }

            if (structure.StructureName == StructureNames.Data)
            {
                DetectCommand(package, matchedProtocol);
                componentDataLength = package.Command.ReceiveBytesLength == 0 ? componentDataLength : package.Command.ReceiveBytesLength;
            }

            var component = new PackageComponent<byte[]>
            {
                ComponentName = structure.StructureName,
                DataType = structure.DataType,
                ComponentIndex = structure.StructureIndex,
                ComponentContent = bufferBytes.SubBytes(currentIndex, currentIndex + componentDataLength)
            };

            currentIndex += componentDataLength;

            package[structure.StructureName] = component;
        }

        DecodeCommand(package);

        return package;
    }

    public IProtocolPackage EncodeCommand(IProtocolCommand command, Dictionary<string, byte[]> paramBytes = null)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void DoDelive(IProtocolPackage package, IPackageSource source)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public IDataConverter<byte> DataConverter { get; set; }

    public void DecodeCommand(IProtocolPackage<byte> package)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void DetectCommand(IProtocolPackage<byte> package, IProtocol matchedProtocol)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: Check if namespaces are same, may be you have duplicate interface definitions in two namespaces?

Comment: Post the code where you are getting actual error. The code you posted do not seems to have any error.

Comment: Where does this error *occur*? I can´t see any code converting one class instance to another.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The class `ChargingPileCommandCoder` implements `IProtocolPackage<byte[]>` but **not** `IProtocolPackage<byte>`.

Answer (score 1):

When I paste this into VS, I first get warnings about the interfaces accessability.

When making them public, I get the message that ChargingPileProtocolPackage is not assignable to IProtocolPackage, and indeed that is correct beacuase it implements IProtocolPackage.

When changing the signature of DecodeCommand as follows, the warning is gone:

```
public void DecodeCommand(IProtocolPackage<byte[]> package)
```